# How can I find all buildings of a certain type in Anno 1404?

Tags: anno-1404

In Anno 1404, is there any way to find out how many buildings of a certain type (for example Carpenters) I have built in my settlement and where they are located? This is a not an issue in small settlements, but larger cities can be quite confusing.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Have you tried clicking on your town center?  I can't recall how it worked in 1404, but in 2070, there are tabs that show this type of info, and you can click building types to cycle through all of your buildings of that type.

Comment: @agent86: There is no such thing as a town center in Anno 1404, but I have tried the warehouse and could not find any info there. Perhaps I have overlooked something?

Comment: I'm talking about the building at the center of your city - in 1404 it's called the [Marketplace](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Marketplace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question: The Venice Addon to Anno 1404 solves exactly this problem: By building the [Bailiwick](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Bailiwick), you can see stats on all buildings on the same island and also reduce maintenance costs for production buildings.